# Flutter StreamBuilder to query sub-collection of document in a sub-collection in Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

In Flutter I'm using a StreamBuilder to get a sub-collection of a document in a collection from Firestore. But I get null and the progress indicator just keeps spinning.

The structure is as follows:

```
/dev/l0WwBF4HXBZ59hMGcKvY/meas_weight
```

This is the console view:
[image]

And this is my code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection('dev')
            .document('l0WwBF4HXBZ59hMGcKvY')
            .collection('meas_weight')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            default:
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  DocumentSnapshot document = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text('${document['value']}'),
                  );
                },
              );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

If I just query for the parent collection "dev" it works fine, and I get a list of the documents in it. But not if I try to get the "meas_weight" sub-collection.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: As per: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document

"Retrieving a list of collections is not possible with the mobile/web client libraries. You should only look up collection names as part of administrative tasks in trusted server environments. If you find that you need this capability in the mobile/web client libraries, consider restructuring your data so that subcollection names are predictable."

Comment: Thank you Mario. I was hoping to find a solution without having to restructure the data. But I guess that I've reached the limit.

Answer (score 2):

The problem turned out to be related to the rules. I had not realized that the rules don't apply to sub-collections unless they are explicitly set. That's why I didn't bother to include them in my question. See documentation here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#hierarchical_data

So first I renamed the collection as "meas_weights", and then I changed the rule like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /dev/{user} {
      allow read,write: if request.auth != null;
      match /meas_weights/{meas_weight} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I was able to get the documents in the sub-collection.